# Is this proof involving quantifiers valid?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Is this a valid proof? If so can someone explain it?

Prove that: $\forall x: \exists y : (x \leq y) \land \lnot I(y)$

Premises: $\forall x: \forall y: [I(x) \land \lnot I(y)] \implies (x \lt y)$ and $\exists z : \lnot I(z)$

Proof: We let $a$ be an arbitrary element. Then $I(a) \lor \lnot I(a)$.

Case 1: $I(a)$
By rules of instantiation and our second premise we instantiate b such that $\lnot I(b)$. $I(a) \land \lnot I(b)$ so by modus
ponens and our first premise, $a \lt b$ and by our definition of $\leq$, $a \leq b$. Therefore $(a \leq b) \land \lnot I(b)$. Then
by existence, $\exists y : (a \leq y) \land \lnot I(y)$.

Case 2: $\lnot I(a)$
We know $a = a$, so by definition $a \leq a$. We assumed $\lnot I(a)$, so using conjunction we have $(a \leq a) \land \lnot I(a)$.
Thus by existence  $\exists y : (a \leq y) \land \lnot I(y)$.

Then in both cases, by generalization, we have $\forall x: \exists y : (x \leq y) \land \lnot I(y)$.

For case 2: if we took $a$ as arbitrary why did we use rule of existence and not generalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is exactly correct! Well done.

And you used existential introduction in both cases exactly because you were trying to prove an existential: $\exists y (a \leq y \land \neg I(y))$

It's only after that proof by cases that you introduce a universal ... which is why you introduced $a$ as an arbitrary object.

Yes, it may feel weird that in case $2$ you end up creating the existential using the same object as that you end up creating the universal at the end with ... this is certainly unusual for a proof ... but it is all perfectly valid!

Indeed, when the statement says: $\forall x \exists y ...$, then of course for some of the $x$'s the $y$ *could* be the same as the $x$ ... and that's exactly what is going on here.